# Visual Studio 2013 C# - Database connection with MS SQL 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012

I'm doing a tutorial on youtube and everything worked fine until now, when i want to add data in the database. I am using Visual Studio 2013 and MS SQL 2012. Here is my code:

[image: App.config]

[image: Form1]

[image: frmNewStudent]

[image: DB_Access]

[image]

As you can see, conn is null and i don't understand why, when i press the button "test connection" with the database in Visual Studio it says OK.

Comment: Change tutorial, this is wrong on many levels. By the way, as you can see many people don't like images of code. Post the code text instead

Comment: First of all. First do as @Steve says, most of it is horrible software development practice. Second, the problem is probably your connection string. Have you checked if the database works or exists?

Comment: You probably shouldn't do a tutorial if you are not *really good* at the technology

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I am sorry for posting images but i am new here. How can i test if database works? What tutorial do you recommend for something like this?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem. I removed configSections from app.config and works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

try to call connection in DB_Access constructor by using

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString
```

reference .

Comment: I replaced "ConString" with "myConnectionString" . What reference do you mean?